# How to solve this error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The 'request' argument must be string. Received type undefined using nuxt.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js encountered this error  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The 'request' argument must be string. Received type undefined while running the project what does this error mean?

I tried npm install nothing works.

I think it's node js problem.

Following is my config file

```
const pkg = require('./package')


module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'},
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Source+Sans+Pro'}
]

  }
```

Comment: its not enough info. Something in your code cause it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `package-lock.json` was the issue when I got that error. I've removed it and reinstalled node modules. It works fine ever after. You might want to check if that would work in your situation.